# How to customize or change Jenkins Web GUI (theme)?

Tags: java, rest, user-interface, jenkins

How can I build a web UI on top of Jenkins web UI?

I have multiple Jenkins instanse running across different build farm and I need to collaborate all these Jenkins status into a single web ui.

Comment: Can you vote up if my answer help you?thanks!

Comment: This is not allowing me to vote up

Comment: and tick?you remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many options to have a diffent UI for Jenkins, I recommend you these options:

- Build a custom UI using your favorite frontend framework and integrating the frontend with Jenkins REST API.
- Use a theme for Jenkins, for example [Jenkins Material Theme](http://afonsof.com/jenkins-material-theme/).
- Use [Jenkins Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/).
- Create a custom theme for Jenkins.

The more easy is using a theme but if you need a 100% custom UI you can create a frontend.

Answer (score 1):

REST API + your favorite frontend javascript framework (angular, reactjs).